# Using answer in if

Tags: java, string, if-statement, equals

I ran into this problem. This is my code:

```
String answer;

System.out.println("Choose a day");
answer = tastatur.nextLine();


if(svar.equals("saturday"))
  System.out.println("Saturday");
```

I want to use the answer in the if statement.

Comment: Can you be more explicit than "does not work"?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with "using the answer"?

Comment: `svar.equals("saturday")` maybe should be `answer.equals("saturday")` ?

Comment: We are not here to teach java!!!

Comment: Actually we are here to help people with problems that are trying to learn java and this falls into that category

Comment: Both `authors` are fuming over downvotes! I request everyone to close this quetion as incomplete,missing information has been provided,that too with OP's no intent to correct and learn!

Comment: @shekharsuman at least I agree with you one time lol

Comment: Please specify what is *not-working* if you don't want random answers based on assumptions.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change svar to answer

Comment: @brso05 Downvotes to an answer aren't for the correctness of the answer, but for the answer's usefulness.

Comment: @shekharsuman DOnt assume. I am not even bothered about down votes. "fuming" is a very strong word.

Comment: It is useful people are just trying to help maybe you should read what stackover flow is all about helping people

Comment: @SofieBreidablik Please elaborate on your question; help? is a little on the broad side.

Comment: @LittleChild-Sorry,but my intentions were only for `brso05`, I don't know how my hands did this to you also. SORRY!

Comment: the op does not even care to elaborate anything lol

Comment: @brso05 In the grand scheme of SO, this question and any answers probably aren't too helpful to the community, as the poster of this question appears very unfamiliar with Java.

Comment: It does help the person asking the question

Comment: @brso05 ...which the poster can indicate by upvoting the answer(s) helpful to them!

Comment: @brso05 yes it will help op but he/she can easily find the solution to him/her problem if he/she tried a little.

Comment: She is trying by posting on SO

Comment: @brso05 Main purpose of SO is not to help only asker, but to help people with same problem. That is why questions needs to be valid (it needs to be clear, and contain short but full code which will let us and future reader reproduce described problem).

Comment: Main purpose to help asker secondary purpose to help others

Comment: @brso05 Serious question: where does it say that on the site? I haven't seen those two items prioritized anywhere.

Comment: Then don't comment on them

Comment: @brso05 "Main purpose to help asker secondary purpose to help others –  brso05" Where does it say one is primary and one is secondary?

Comment: @brso05 At start of [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) you can see that "we're working together to build a **library** of detailed answers to every question about programming". You don't write book just for one person. Same goes here, while writing question and answer we should focus mainly on future readers. Helping OP is important, but we require from askers and answerers some quality. Askers need to provide question which can be found by people with similar problem, answerers should write in their posts: explanation of problem, solution, explanation of solution.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking at the wrong variable.

```
if( answer.equals("saturday") ){
   System.out.println("Saturday")
}
```

What's the logic?
You are reading what the user is entering into the `answer` variable. In your code you are checking the `svar` variable while you should be checking the `answer` variable. If indeed the user entered Saturday, you will print it on the screen. Else, not.

`equalsIgnoreCase()` is a better method to use because `Saturday` and `saturday` are different in the sense that one has a capitalized S and the other does not. `equals()` will treat them as different.

You have said that Java is new to you. I hope you are initializing the `tastatur` variable properly as:

```
BufferedReader tastatur = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

and using the `import java.io.*` in your program.

---

As an aside, please read the [official tutorials provided by Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). They are a good resource. Ask questions on StackOverflow when you have run out of luck while looking for answers yourself. With that said, welcome to StackOverflow where we very mercilessly close questions if they do not meet our standards or contain spam.

Comment: downvoter's comment will be appreciated

Comment: See,downvotes removed!

Comment: +1 for being descriptive and awesome

Comment: I did not down-vote. But this is an answer solely based on *assumptions* to a very poor question. I discourage such answers because they tend to lead *us nowhere*. I still can't figure out the question.

Comment: @TheLostMind yes, you are right. I am assuming a lot many things. :) The problem as well may be in OP's declaration of `main()` and that would mean my answer is wrong.